# Автодополнение текста

Tags: phpstorm

В notepad++ есть удобная штука - он умеет подставлять (дополнять) любой текст, если он уже где-то есть в файле.

Например, где-то в файле было использовано слово "пользователь", и мне оно опять понадобилось, я начинаю печатать "по", и мне notepad++ выдаёт все варианты слов, которые начинаются на эти буквы.

Можно ли как-то повторить этот функционал в PHPStorm? Пока я нашёл только, что он умеет это делать лишь с ключевыми словами, вроде названий функций, переменных и т.п. А хотелось, чтобы и произвольный текст тоже умел дополнять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code | Completion | Cyclic Expand Word (Alt+/).

Comment: А я ведь смотрел на это, но, видимо, не сработало, из-за того, что не работают горячие клавиши с участием alt. Спасибо.  
Жалко, что список не выпадает. Нельзя, чтобы просто список выпадал?

Comment: Клавиши с Alt могут не работать из-за вашего видеодрайвера от Intel: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-195 . Либо смените хоткеи в Settings | Keymap. Список пока нельзя, голосуйте за http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6021 .

Comment: @CrazyCoder, да я сменил клавишу сразу, мне всё равно неудобно использовать слэш.
За список оставил свой голос, было бы здорово.

Comment: @frgs, так смените сочетание еще и в phpStorm.